# NextJS toggle button not working with htmlFor

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, toggle

I am trying to create a toggler when clicked, will hide the elements. So, when it's working, it will hide the sidebar, but I am stuck at trying to hide the elements.

I am using NextJS

```js
<input type="checkbox" id="sidebarToggle" className={styles.sidebarToggle} />
<div className={styles.dashboard}>
  <div className={styles.sidebar}>
    <div className={styles.sidebarHeader}>
      <h3 class={styles.brand}>
        <span><img src="/unlink.svg" alt="unlink"/></span>
        <span>easyTechServ</span>
      </h3> 
      <label htmlFor="sidebarToggle"><img src="/menu-alt.svg" alt="menu-alt"/></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS:

```css
.sidebarToggle:checked ~ .sidebar .sidebarHeader h3 span:last-child,
.sidebarToggle:checked ~ .sidebar li span:last-child {    
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector is incorrect. You try to use the sibling selector (`~`), but `.sidebar` is not a sibling of `.sidebarToggle` so it will never be hidden.

Also, try not to over-specify your CSS selectors and remove unnecessary specificity.

Check the following HTML+CSS snippet:

```css
.sidebarToggle:checked ~ .dashboard .brand span:last-child,
.sidebarToggle:checked ~ .dashboard li span:last-child {
  display: none;
}

.brand span:last-child {
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="sidebarToggle" class="sidebarToggle" />
<div class="dashboard">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebarHeader">
      <h3 class="brand">
        <span><img src="/unlink.svg" alt="unlink"/></span>
        <span>easyTechServ</span>
      </h3>
      <label for="sidebarToggle">
        <img src="/menu-alt.svg" alt="menu-alt"/>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```